# SQL update with join and select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have have the following query. What I am trying to do is to update the Type field in HeaderTbl based on the value from the DetailTbl for a given Id.

```
update HeaderTbl
set HeaderTbl.Type = DetailTbl.Type
from HeaderTbl 
join DetailTbl on HeaderTbl.Id = DetailTbl.Id
```

For a HeaderTbl id, there can be multiple DetailTbl Ids.

Say for a given Id (lets say Id=5) we have 7 Ids that are Id=5 in the DetailTbl.
With the above query, it will hit the HeaderTbl then 7 times and update it - correct? The result that will stick will the last 7th one, correct?

I am doing a large update so just want to make sure I do not overlook anything.

Comment: what do you mean by "The result that will stick will the last 7th one" ?

Comment: Why not just test it?  But you've got a larger problem - how would it know what the 'last' detail record was?  You're probably going to need to give some differentiating information to make it only get one record (I'm not sure what happens if the join returns more than one row, anyways).

Comment: In my case, of Id=5, the last or 7th record where Id=5 in DetailTbl will be the value that gets updated in HeaderTbl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update on each row will be done only once. You can see this using "Actual Execution Plan" or using the OUTPUT clause.
Ifin DetailTbl table for ID is more than one different values ​​in Type column, the result is not deterministic.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82363/1